# smothly open and close navigation drawer in android

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation, navigation-drawer

I create custom layout for drawer-layout but the app is lagging when i close drawer. I Check many tutorials and stackoverflow solution but can't found any one for my help. 
I follow bellow tutorial but all this are lagging. I just make a vary simple project with navigation view there are no other functionality.

https://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/

Can any one give me a complete tutorial? can you describe what will be the resign?

My code:

nev_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="25dp">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/thumb01"

        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_favourite"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/drawer_My_Favourite"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="menuclick"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="  My Favourite"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/drawer_menu_text_size"

            />


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_download" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/OfflineVideo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="menuclick"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Offline Videos"
            android:textColor="@color/drawer_menu_default_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/drawer_menu_text_size" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"

        >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Home"

            android:title="   Home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Most_Popular"

            android:title="   Most Popular" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Movies"

            android:title="   Movies" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Dramas"

            android:title="   Dramas" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Tv_Show"

            android:title="   Tv Show" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Music_Video"

            android:title="   Music Video" />

    </group>


</menu>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"

        app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_state_list"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. hardwareAccelerated="true" remove apps lagging

```
 android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Comment: It solves my problem. and i also use bellow code

 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

  //put the statements which are need to be executed after closing drawer. 

        }
    }, 100);

Answer (score 2):

On drawer item click, first close drawer and delay all the execution of other statements for some milliseconds. like this

```
    drawer.close();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

  //put the statements which are need to be executed after closing drawer. 

        }
    }, 300);
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of doing this you can directly create a new navigation bar activity and can edit as per your requirements.
in Android studio
click on file>new>Activity>Navigation drawer activity
thanks

Comment: Thanks for your  comment. I also use that but when i set image and customize that time it start lagging. did you check netflix apps? isn't this  so smooth?

Comment: Can you put the screenshot ?

Comment: ok I will add screenshot but may be nothing help you with screenshot because when i navigation drawer close or open that time it lagging.